# specify what files from the repository are included in master.zip when using the "Download ZIP" link on GitHub

Tags: github

Is it possible to specify what files are included or not included in the zip file when you use the "Download ZIP" link in a repository? Or do I need to make my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your own: even the [GitHub API only exposes the archive link](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link), without any customization.

You would get a  tarball or zipball archive for a *full* repository, not for a subset.

Comment: Understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can click on specific file and then "Raw" and download them separately and ZIP them after that.

This is useful for a few files project / small files though.